# How to pass element ID from one component to another in Angular?

Tags: angular

before asking the question i have find few similar question on stack overflow about the problem i'm facing. i'm trying to pass ID from one template to another. my first template looks like this

```
<View
[id] = "'some_id'"
[Behavior] = "behavior"> </View>
```

in my second template i have this.

```
<canvas id="id"></canvas>
```

to move data from one component to another i'm using `@input` decorators. works fine. inside the first component i have to create object of second component.  in both components i'm using `ngOnInit` methods, first one creates objects, second one initializes them.  problem starts here, when creating object it do not have id yet. its undefined.

```
      this.obj= MyObj.create(document.querySelector('#some_id'))
```

i have used `@Input`, `AfterViewInit`, `OnChanges`, `*ngIf` to force somehow id not to be null or undefined. but failling. can anyone give me a good advice how to assing id from one template to another?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `[id] = "'some_id'"`, the input variable is actually `id`. `'some_id'` is the value of that input variable.

Try the following

child.component.ts

```js
@Input() id: string;
```

child.component.html

```html
<canvas id="id"></canvas>
```

**Update**

May be calling a custom input variable the same as a built-in property is doing something unintended. Try using other name

child.component.ts

```js
@Input() customId: string;
```

child.component.html

```html
<canvas id="customId"></canvas>
```

parent.component.html

```html
<app-child [customId]="'some_id'"...></app-child>
```

Comment: i'm getting same error with output/input. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Comment: yes i know how to pass data , i have amde mistake in typing of quesiton. i have input property with [id] = "'some_id'" and i have     @Input() id : string; then i'm using like this canvas id="'id'" but error is same

Comment: I've posted an update. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: @Michale D, nope. i thought about this as well. it does not work. problem is a lifecycle hook i guess, child component have to wait for user input, i'm new in angular and have no idea how to do this properly.  when i'm debugging, first parrent component oninit is called and then child component oninit. when parent oninit try to create object child component has no id.

Comment: Now I get it. One workaround I could think of is to create an event emitter in the child component and emit the object. That way we are sure the element is in the DOM when you manipulate it in the parent component.

Comment: Event Emitter is not a good option mate :) there have to be a better and simpler way.

Comment: IMO Event emitter is as simple as it gets. It's just a simple wrapper around `Subject`.

Comment: event emitter is good when you are using custom events. id is not event for sure.

Comment: That is true. But what you need is more or less an event. Something like `idCreated` event that lets the parent know the ID has been created in the DOM. I'd say it's not a far fetch from the expected use case of an event emitter. And also like I said it's a simple wrapper around `Subject`. So it's not too complex of a workaround

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing a string with data binding it means you are assigning constant string some_id to `id` inside children component.

```
[id] = "'some_id'"
```

In below, you are binding the parent component class property `some_id` to the `id` Input property of children component.

```
[id]="some_id"
```